# Что означает (unsigned char)~0 >> 1?

Tags: c

Помогите разобраться в коде! Нужно максимальное и минимально значение signed и unsigned char. Не понимаю, что значит >> и ~

```
signed char max_char_s = (char)((unsigned char)~0 >> 1);
signed char min_char_s = max_char_s + 1;
unsigned char max_char_u = (unsigned char)~0;
unsigned char min_char_u = 0;
printf("Signed Char: Max = %d, Min = %d\n", max_char_s, min_char_s);
printf("Unsigned Char: Max = %u, Min = %u\n", max_char_u, min_char_u);
```

Comment: Побитовый сдвиг вправо и побитовое отрицание (инверсия). Разве этого нет в списках операторов языка?

Comment: Кстати, в вашем коде я что-то не вижу `>>` :)

Comment: @Harry, форматирование съело первую строку кода. Поправил.

Answer (score 4):

***NB** оба примера упрощены, чтобы было легче понять*.

`~` - инверсия всех битов числа. `~0` - значение в котором все биты установлены. Если было *00000000<sub>2</sub>*, получится *11111111<sub>2</sub>*.

`>>` - смещает биты на несколько позиций вправо, старшие биты обнуляются. В случае `>> 1` если было *11111111<sub>2</sub>*, станет *01111111<sub>2</sub>*.

Но лучше не играть с битами, а использовать стандарт:

[limits.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void) {
    printf(" CHAR_MIN = %5d\n"  ,  CHAR_MIN);
    printf(" CHAR_MAX = %5d\n\n",  CHAR_MAX);
    printf("SCHAR_MIN = %5d\n"  , SCHAR_MIN);
    printf("SCHAR_MAX = %5d\n\n", SCHAR_MAX);
    printf("UCHAR_MAX = %5u\n"  , UCHAR_MAX);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion char-limits.c
>
> $ ./a.out 
>  CHAR_MIN =  -128
>  CHAR_MAX =   127
>
> SCHAR_MIN =  -128
> SCHAR_MAX =   127
>
> UCHAR_MAX =   255
> ```